# QGIS Copy paste points from one layer to another

Tags: layer, geo, qgis

Well I have an **outline** layer and a **region** layer.

The region for sure sure using the outline, so it would be great if I could select some important point from the outline layer and than copy paste it to the region layer.

How is that possible?

Comment: This isn't a programming question - you'll have better luck with a QGIS tutorial or barring that, http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sure but I already had a look and did not find anything useful. There is no QGIS forum and the creator say to use SO. So it would be great if you could send helpful links.

Comment: Please read more carefully. The [QGIS support page](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/support.html) explicitly links http://gis.stackexchange.com/ which is not the same as SO. Also, several other avenues of support are listed on that page.

Comment: Indeed you are right. Is it possible to move the question to qis...? But I don't think so. Anyways I found a good alternative to copying points. So it's fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to go is another. Let's say we have layer **outline**(o) and **region**(r).

You create the polygon in **o** and after that select it. Now hit CTRL+C for copying. Now switch to **r** and paste it there with CTRL+V. It should be the same place now. Don't forget to disable the view of polygon from **o** for sure. Now in **r** you can use the **Split Features** from the **Advanced Digitizing**. Now split the polygon at the place where you need it. Delete the second unwanted polygon after that.